# How to enable error display on browser screen?

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-dev-server, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I spend some time to find a solution to output ESLint errors on browser screen after saving the file (while hot reloading).
My environment:

```
Webpack
ES6
Typescript
```

What could be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is to use use the following combination of plugins in `webpack.js` project:

```
...
plugins: [
  new ESLintPlugin({
    files: 'src/**/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    configFile: '.eslintrc.json',
    lintDirtyModulesOnly: true,
    emitError: true,
    emitWarning: true,
    failOnError: false,
    failOnWarning: false,
  }),
  new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({}),
],
...
```

Assumptions:

- you use webpack.js as a bundle tool
- you have configured `.eslintrc.json` for your project
- you have installed and imported `ESLintPlugin` and `ErrorOverlayPlugin` into your webpack.js file